# Rails communication with web services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am developing a Rails web shop application and I have the following system set up:

- 2 separate web services (very simple Rails apps with the same code but different databases)
- Main Rails application which stores information from both web services.

The main application gets some information from both web services (in JSON format) and has to choose items (based on price). For testing purposes I currently take all items from both and add them to the main application's database. However, when items are being stored in the main database (with a simple `.create` and a hash with all parameters it seems as if it's adding on item multiple times and thus it takes a very long time.

First, what is generally a good strategy for doing this type of thing - getting data from the web services and storing it? Also, at what point do I want to ask for an update of the main database? It seems too much if it is every time a user connects.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a key value for id in the data... if not you should define one.  Most likely an auto incrementing integer ID since this is tagged as rails. Although you'll probably want a UUID (perhaps [SecureRandom.uuid](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid)) since the two data sources are independent of each other, which adds significant complexity in a rails app

In that case you could use @model = Model.find_or_create_by(key_value: value) to avoid duplicates being created, and @model.update_attributes (essentially use an update action) to only modify what has changed.

Comment: I do have an id column and was considering to use it for this purpose, but the two web services might have different entries with the same id. I think it would be more complex if the main app had to coordinate the ids of the web services.

Comment: then you should use a uuid or create a unique compound key from the data